# WinRT timeout during a webrequest to detect slow internet connections

Tags: c#, xaml, asynchronous, windows-8

Is there a sample code available online to get WinRT to determine if its a slow internet connection within the first second of a web-request call so that I can cancel the request and switch to a local file at the start of the program. Metro requirements expect the app to boot up under 5 seconds and I need my web-request (of 300kb) to return well before that. its usually fast on WiFi but 3G speed may vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see if you are running on a 3G or WiFi connection by using the [connectioncost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.connectioncost.aspx) api.

When you are on 3G you could consider using the local file anyway and then attempt to update it on the background. Additionally you might increase your logic further by checking if the user is currently roaming or even if he or she is approaching his or her datalimit, all which might influence your decision on where to load from. All this can be done through the same API.

You are also mixing up things a little as far as the 5 seconds for your app to start go. Your app can actually take 15 seconds give or take to provide something and only 5 seconds to suspend before you are forcibly cut off. If the 15 seconds isn't enough to start with you can also replace the default splash screen .. with your own splash screen and continue loading as long as you like. Keep in mind your user might not like it.

Why not load the local file and then try to update it on the background? I am not sure about your use case.

Comment: Sure, will try that and get back

Comment: How do I get the relative speed of the connection regardless of the type, so that I can cancel a webrequest after a few seconds?

Comment: I'm now loading a local cached file and I update it later when the loading completes, need to make smooth animations for the transitions